# $G_f^\theta$ is $A_4$ or $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ irreducible polynomial of degree 4, $u \in \mathbb{C}$ a root of $f(x)$. Prove that there are not subfields $K$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset \mathbb{Q} (u)$ if and only if the galois group of $f(x)$, $G(N/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G_f^\theta$, is $A_4$ or $S_4$.

$N$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $K$ is a proper subfield between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} (u)$

How to prove it?

Comment: Have you at least gotten one of the directions? If the group is $A_4$ or $S_4$ try to confirm the claim.

For the other direction, you might just try looking at all of the other subgroups of $S_4$ and showing that none of them has the desired property.

Comment: I supposed that there are not subfields and that $G_f^\theta$ is not $A_4$ and $S_4$ then as $f(x)$ is irreducible in one case $G_f^\theta$ is $V$ the klein group so I concluded that $\mathbb{Q} (u)=N$ which means that the other roots are in $\mathbb{Q} (u)$ but I do not know if it is a contradiction.

Comment: You just have to use the basic properties of the Galois correspondence. Where are you stuck, exactly?